# Unable to get Parse iOS SDK LiveQuery to work. Always get "cannot decode json into"

Tags: swift, parse-server, parse-ios-sdk

I have a parse server implementation and I'm using an iOS app to interact with the server. Everything works as expected except **ParseLiveQuery**.

This is the implementation I have:

For simplicity purposes, the subscription to ParseLiveQuery is on the appDelegate right after the parse SDK is initialized:

```
Parse.Initialize(with: configuration); //appId, clientKey, server

//ParseLiveQuery
let query = Test.query()!.whereKey("isActive", equalTo: true);

let subscription = Client.shared.subscribe(query);
    
subscription.handle(Event.updated) { query, parseObject in

      print("\(parseObject)")
}
```

The Test object is just a simple swift Test class:

```
class Test: PFObject, PFSubclassing{
    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Test";
    }

    @NSManaged var isActive:Bool;
}
```

Looking around it says I need to subclass using **PFObject** and also conform to **PFSubclassing**.

So when I go into the Parse Dashboard and I update this "Test" object, I see a trigger on the app side but with an error saying "cannot decode json into "

[image]

I think I must be missing something basic about ParseLiveQuery since I can't find anything about this anywhere.

I appreciate any help with this issue!

Comment: It would appear that the json being returned cannot be decoded into the expected type.  But as you haven't indicated what the json is or what type it is meant to be decoded to it's unlikely you'll get much detailed help.

Comment: @flanker This error is internal to the Parse SDK iOS so I guess it should handle the JSON file by itself. I really don't have control over this. My guess is that it receive the object from the server as JSON and parses it to the "Test" PFObject. My error might be how I declared the Test object which is not recognized by the SDK maybe.